# ASP.NET MVC 5 - Custom attribute for validating checkbox

Tags: model-view-controller

I am trying to validate a required checkbox in mvc5. For the most part its validating/working...my issue is ***its not firing the ErrorMessage***. In other words its preventing me from submitting when not checked but without displaying the *Please Accept the Terms & Conditions* as its supposed to.

My Code below

Custom attribute for validating checkbox

```
    namespace Checkboxtest.Models
{ 
    //Making Custom attribute for validating checkbox 
    // IClientValidatable for client side Validation
    public class MustBeTrueAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
    {
        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            return value != null && value is bool && (bool)value;
        }
        // Implement IClientValidatable for client side Validation 
        public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
        {
            return new ModelClientValidationRule[] {
 new ModelClientValidationRule { ValidationType = "checkboxtrue", ErrorMessage = this.ErrorMessage } };
        }
    }
}
```

Domain Model

```
    [Display(Name = "Terms and Conditions")]
    [MustBeTrue(ErrorMessage = "Please Accept the Terms & Conditions")]  
    public bool TermsAndConditions { get; set; }
```

Checkbox Form

```
            @using (Html.BeginForm())
            {
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.TermsAndConditions) 
                    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.TermsAndConditions)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.TermsAndConditions)
                </div> 
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success submit">Submit</button>
            }
```

Can anyone let me know what I am doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: You have added this to the layout?  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

Answer (score 0):

Here is modification which should help:

```
namespace Checkboxtest.Models
{ 
    //Making Custom attribute for validating checkbox 
    // IClientValidatable for client side Validation
    public class MustBeTrueAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
    {
        private const string defaultError = "'{0}' must be true.";
        public MustBeTrueAttribute() : base(defaultErrorMessage)
        {
        }

        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            return value != null && value is bool && (bool)value;
        }
        // Implement IClientValidatable for client side Validation 
        public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
        {
            return new ModelClientValidationRule[] {
            new ModelClientValidationRule { ValidationType = "checkboxtrue", ErrorMessage = this.ErrorMessage } };
        }
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return String.Format(ErrorMessageString, name);
    }
 }
```